# Why object.__proto__ can be changeable to primitive if object create with Object.create(null);

Tags: javascript, prototype

When we create normal object with **__proto__** property. Property can be only object or null and if we want to change **proto** to primitive type this is still Object.prototype.

```
const obj1 = {
  __proto__: "test"
};

console.log(obj1.__proto__)// Still Object.prototype not change to "test"
```

But if we create object via **Object.create(null)** object's **proto** property can be change primitive type.

```
const obj2 = Object.create(null);

obj2.__proto__ = "test";
console.log(obj2.__proto__) // "test"
```

**So I know The __proto__ is not a property of an object, but an accessor property of Object.prototype:**

 
My question is how we can create accessor property like **proto** manually?

I want to create one getter and setter inside **Object.prototype** and this getter and setter can't be overridable like **proto** internal property.

For example if I declare getter and setter like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "lastName", {
    get() {
        return "Sofiyev"
    },
    set(v) {

    },
});
```

lastName property not not overridable like this.

```
  const murad = {};
  murad.lastName = 123
  console.log(murad.lastName) //Sofiyev
```

but overridable like this.

```
const murad = {
    lastName: "123"
};

console.log(murad.lastName) // 123
```

**This is interesting for me why __proto__ not overridable like my last example**

Comment: What aspect of `__proto__` is it that you're trying to recreate?

Comment: In my first example why __proto__ not work like property it work like accessor property of Object.prototype. I declare it inside object like property. And can we create like this accessor property?

Comment: Edit is much improved. And unfortunately the answer is **you can't**. Every object is descended from `Object.prototype`, *except* objects created by `Object.create(null)`. So any modifications you make will not apply there.

Comment: @MuradSofiyev This is because a specific feature of object literals in web-compatible browser environments. It's not something you can create yourself.

Comment: @JaredSmith But this is very funny. Look my first example actually İ override  __proto__ property. This is not same obj.__proto__ = "". I create object with __proto__ property but this is work like setter. I don't understand how this possible

Comment: As Bergi said, because this is a special property guaranteed by the spec. You can actually set a different prototype in an object literal but it has to be a proper target: `foo = { __proto__: Array.prototype }; foo.__proto__ === Array.prototype; // true`. Just using a random primitive value is apparently a noop.

Comment: I understand when we write foo__proto__ = Array.prototype how work. __proto__ like setter and check if not primitive this is change [[Prototype]] internal property. But I don't understand why when we use object literal __proto__ also can be work like setter :(

Comment: @MuradSofiyev It doesn't work like a setter. `Object.prototype.__proto__` has nothing to with this. `{__proto__: x}` is like `Object.create(x)`.

Comment: @Bergi Okay last question and I finish this discuss. You say Object.prototype.__proto__ has nothing to with this. But how possible if object create with Object.create(null) and we change change this object's __proto__ property to primitive type?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev The inherited `.__proto__` does have something to do with trying to change that property *after* the object has been created. `o = {__proto__: x}` and `o.__proto__ = x` are two different things that have their own modes of action.